# Pixel Bender to Access iOS API?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ios

Working on a Flash iOS app and I need to utilize a couple Apple APIs.  I was thinking, would it be possible to write Pixel Bender classes to access their API?  If so, could someone provide a small example to get started?

Or is there a different / better approach for this?

Comment: Pixel Bender is a shading language. You write kernels which processes a stream of pixels, not classes. I do not see the link between Pixel Bender kernels and the iOS API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way to access the iOS' API that I know of as of this writing.

Comment: +1.  If Adobe adds a feature to access native APIs; it will most likely be implemented as documented here:  http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/devices/pdfs/DevelopingActionScriptExtensionsForAdobeAIR.pdf .  As I understand it--from that document--this is already implemented in "Adobe AIR for TV".  I'm unclear if such an implementation would violate Apples terms of service, though.